# Why use macro to call functions

Tags: c, linux, macros, linux-kernel

I was studying the Linux wireless subsystem code and noticed this code (in ieee80211_rx_handlers):

It first defines the macro:

```
 #define CALL_RXH(rxh)                   \
         do {                            \
                 res = rxh(rx);          \
                     if (res != RX_CONTINUE) \
                         goto rxh_next;  \
         } while (0);
```

Then the macro is used to call a series of functions:

```
 CALL_RXH(ieee80211_rx_h_check_more_data)

 CALL_RXH(ieee80211_rx_h_uapsd_and_pspoll)

 CALL_RXH(ieee80211_rx_h_sta_process)

 CALL_RXH(ieee80211_rx_h_decrypt)

 CALL_RXH(ieee80211_rx_h_defragment)

 CALL_RXH(ieee80211_rx_h_michael_mic_verify)
```

My question is, why not just call the functions directly like:

```
ieee80211_rx_h_check_more_data(rx);

ieee80211_rx_h_uapsd_and_pspoll(rx); 

...
```

Is it just for the sake of outlining the code for easy reading?

Comment: You realize that what you propose is different from what is actually happening, right?

Comment: I guess it is because of the `goto`.

Comment: There is a small logic in the MACRO, if you just expand it, it will expand the source file size, also, the MACRO can avoid errors when duplicating this logic, I guess

Comment: Yup, what is proposed is not the same as how the macro should be expanded exactly. Sorry for the ambiguity. I can understand how the macro works. I am just wondering if there are any other reasons to use the macro instead of exact expansion, other than reducing the code size and less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

Each use of the macro expands into the `if` check and `goto`, not just a single function call.

The `if` tests differ only by which function is called to produce the condition. Because the code would otherwise be repetitive, they used a macro to generate the boilerplate.

They could perhaps have interspersed calls `res = xyz( rx );` with a macro expanding to the `if … goto` part, and then the macro would not take any parameter. How much gets encapsulated into the macro is a matter of code factoring style.

Answer (score 0):

The **do {} while(0)** Macro could be easily used in condition block.

```
#define FUNC1()  doing A; dong B;
#define FUNC2()  do { doing A; doing B; } while(0)
```

We could use FUNC2() in if condition code block like this:

```
if (true)
    FUNC2();
```

But FUNC1() could only be used like this:

```
if (true) {
    FUNC1()
}
```